# .JAR application does not work as intended

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, jar

I am experiencing an issue with a **small GUI Java Application**. The app is a GUI implementation for yt-dlp software which makes it easier for people to download music from Youtube without knowing the terminal syntax of yt-dlp.

Basically whenever I build the artefacts of my program and try to execute the built **.Jar application** my **"Download" button is unresponsive** (does not take any action in regards to its listener). It only happens while using the app in .Jar (while running the program within the JetBrains Intellij IDE it works as intended -> the button reacts and does download the contents). My "Quit" button works as intended (quits the application, both in my IDE and in my .Jar application).

*By unresponsiveness I mean that the program **does not execute its command line statements.**

The code of the downloadButton MouseListner then goes to the download(string link, string outputPath) method which downloads the file.

**downloadButton MouseListener - Code Snippet**

```
  downloadButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (outputPath.getText().isEmpty() || link.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    // some error handling
                } else {
                    try {
                        download(link.getText(), outputPath.getText());
                    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**download(string linkYt, String path) Method - Code Snippet**

```
private void download(String linkYT, String path) throws URISyntaxException {

        // This folder "Libs" is also within the .Jar file.
        Path ytDlpPath = getFilePath("/Libs/yt-dlp.exe");

        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

        Process process = null;
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
        
          processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(ytDlpPath.toString(), "-f", 
          "bestaudio", "-x", "--  audio-format", "wav" , "--output", path + "/%(title)s.%(ext)s",         "ytsearch:" + linkYT);
            
            process = processBuilder.start();
            process.waitFor();

            int exitCode = process.exitValue();

            if (exitCode != 0) {
                // some error handling
            } else {
                // download success 
            }

        } 
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

So far I have tried debugging the code, however as I have previously mentioned -> the "Download" button unresponsiveness only happens while I am using/executing the program within the .Jar file. I cannot seem to find a solution. :(**
Thanks in advance,
Stan**`enter code here`

***EDIT:***
**getFilePath() Method - Code Snippet**

```
    private Path getFilePath(String resourcePath) {
        try {
            return Paths.get(getClass().getResource(resourcePath).toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get resource file path: " + resourcePath, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you go more in detail?

Comment: Yes, it won't be responsive for a *long* time. You need to do the download in a separate thread. I recommend the excellently documented [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Comment: @g00se Well I am not asking "about downloading in a separate thread while Downloading". The issue is that the button does not react to clicking it (anytime). I can click 10 times and nothing happens (no file is downloaded).

Comment: You're quite welcome to totally reject my comment, but you won't get it working otherwise (or without another form of separate-thread creation) ;)

Comment: What does `getFilePath` do? Ultimately, you will have to do some more debugging to narrow this down to a more specific problem. If you can’t reproduce the problem in an IDE, you can run the JAR with remote debugging enabled and connect from the IDE that way. If all else fails, use `System.err.println` statements to log the value of variables to be sure they’re what’s expected.

Comment: @TimMoore I am sorry I forgot to include it in my original Post.I edited the post and added the getFilePath() method Code Snippet.

Comment: @g00se I will try that in a moment.

Comment: You could even use `SwingWorker.publish()` to send `yt-dlp`'s progress report to the gui, having parsed it out of the output stream. Or you could send the whole output